# Limit array length Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

How can I set the an arrays maximum length to only 11. Does this need to be done in the view with LimitTo? or do I need to declare another variable to the controller?

```
       bowlingApp.controller('bowlPoints', function ($scope){
    $scope.bowlPoints = [];

    $scope.addBowlPoints = function() 
    {
      $scope.bowlPoints.push($scope.enteredPoints);
    };
  });

<td ng-repeat="points in bowlPoints track by $index | limitTo:11">{{points}}</td>
```

Comment: How is addBowlPoints called?  What about some validation around that?  If its through a button, then either disable the button or show an alert if bowlPoints is already 11.

Comment: Thanks for the alert idea I can integrate this with the solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While 'limitTo' will probably work in the scenario, another way to do this in the controller would be to set up an if statement before adding points to the array:

```
       bowlingApp.controller('bowlPoints', function ($scope){
$scope.bowlPoints = [];

$scope.addBowlPoints = function() {
  if(($scope.bowlPoints.length + $scope.enteredPoints.length) < 12) {
    $scope.bowlPoints.push($scope.enteredPoints);
  }
};
```

});

Comment: True, I was just giving an example as there isn't much information about the actual use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limitTo` but while using `track by` with `limitTo` you need to make sure you are tracking limited  rows, not all of them. Otherwise you will end up showing all the results not just the limited count. So move track by to the end:

```
   <td ng-repeat="points in bowlPoints | limitTo:11 track by $index">{{points}}</td>
```

But however this does not set your source array restricted to a  specific length, instead it will display only limited count.

*If your main concern is limiting the original array itself, just disable the add functionality on the UI so that the `addBowlPoints` is not called anymore (Assuming this is done from the UI), when the size limit has been reached.*